# Is 'Spy Phone App' safe to use?

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger

I am thinking of using 'Spy Phone App' for tracking different whatsapp accounts. Is it good and safe to use? Have anyone used it? Kindly advice me.

Note: It isn't available in google play but you can find it in google search.

Comment: 'Spy Phone App' is a safe app. There are many people that use it. You can check the reviews here - https://www.capterra.com/p/195854/Spapp-Monitoring/. You can now find it under the name Spapp Monitoring. The website is https://www.spappmonitoring.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to assess this tool is to read the Terms of Service, which is publicly available [here](http://www.spy-phone-app.com/terms_of_service).

A relevant part is this subsection of "Installation and use of software" on the tracked users' devices:

> You can only install and use this app on a device which is your
>   property, or for which you have written permission to install the app,
>   from the owner. You must make anyone who uses a device on which this
>   app is installed, aware of the fact that their internet and phone
>   activity is being monitored and archived. Failure to do the above
>   might be considered breaking of federal and state laws. If you install
>   our software onto a device which you do not own, or don’t have proper
>   consent to do so, we will fully cooperate with all relevant
>   institutions. Spy phone app is not to be used to ‘Stalk’ or ‘Harass’
>   anyone. Spy phone app software must not be used to monitor the
>   smartphone and private life of a spouse, girlfriend, boyfriend, child
>   over 18 without their written consent. Please read all relevant
>   legislation before purchasing and using this app.

Considering the possibility you are asking whether it is safe for you (as the tracker), this is the relevant subsection from the "Privacy policy":

> Our app does not collect any additional info from your device than the
>   ones required for its successful operation. Your data is in safe
>   hands.

And this further down:

> The data collected includes but it is not limited to phone calls, gps
>   logs, sms logs, system logs. We do not collect passwords or credit
>   card numbers.

So, the conclusion: You can only feel safe about this app if you lower your defenses and those of the "friends"/"active voluntary participants" in your scheme.

Unsolicited personal opinion - it's probably a good idea to evaluate why this app is not distributed via Google Play Store.

Comment: What could be the reason for the app not being distributed via Google Play Store?

Comment: @JavedAhmed On Google play tracking apps have more restrictions. For example you can not access sms or phone logs. Many apps are removed from Google play, not just monitoring apps. For example some call recording apps have an unchained version that is not available on Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

**Spy Phone App** is basically a tiny application which allows people to monitor activity that is operated on the particular smartphone. All the activities logs that are performed on the particular smartphone are delivered to your personal online account.

Yes, I used  [spy WhatsApp](https://espiarwhatsappweb.com/) application once. You will have to follow these steps to spy any software:-

1. Install the software on the phone that you wish to track.
2. Log in to your account and check the activities.
3. Customize your setting and activities that you wish to track.

It's also important to know the purpose of cell phone spy software. These are some important things that you track with the help of spy tools:-

1. You can monitor all text messages.
2. Monitor all online chats such as WhatsApp, Facebook, and Snapchat's chat.
3. Track GPS location at present time.
4. You can easily read email and messages remotely.
5. Controls all applications and programs.

Nowadays most of the people think cellphone application software is a scam, but according to me, it basically allows for proper tracking of a smartphone without any physical access.

**I will this article will help you to know about spy software**.